# d3.js error after installing c3.js in angular2

Tags: angular, d3.js, c3.js

I am getting unusual problem,I was working with `d3` and it was working fine but as I installed `c3` in project I am getting several errors related to d3. Please, help as I have ran out of solution.
(Using angular-cli)

I have provided errors and package.json.

Please, help me find bug.

### Error:-

```
 ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-dual-axis-chart/prg-dual-axis-chart.component.ts (203,16): Property 'axisRight' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-vertical-bar-chart/prg-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (125,20): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-vertical-bar-chart/prg-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (183,16): Property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-vertical-bar-chart/prg-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (192,16): Property 'axisBottom' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-vertical-bar-chart/prg-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (201,16): Property 'axisLeft' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-vertical-bar-chart/prg-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (237,29): Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-vertical-bar-chart/prg-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (240,29): Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-vertical-bar-chart/prg-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (245,26): Argument of type '(d: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(datum: any, index: number, outerIndex: number) => Primitive'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Primitive'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-pie-chart/prg-pie-chart.component.ts (157,24): Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-pie-chart/prg-pie-chart.component.ts (163,20): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-pie-chart/prg-pie-chart.component.ts (210,18): Property 'arc' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-pie-chart/prg-pie-chart.component.ts (212,22): Property 'arc' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-pie-chart/prg-pie-chart.component.ts (218,16): Property 'pie' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-pie-chart/prg-pie-chart.component.ts (256,29): Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-pie-chart/prg-pie-chart.component.ts (259,29): Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-donut-chart/prg-donut-chart.component.ts (141,20): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-donut-chart/prg-donut-chart.component.ts (188,18): Property 'arc' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-donut-chart/prg-donut-chart.component.ts (190,22): Property 'arc' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-donut-chart/prg-donut-chart.component.ts (194,18): Property 'pie' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-donut-chart/prg-donut-chart.component.ts (223,29): Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-donut-chart/prg-donut-chart.component.ts (226,29): Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (120,20): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (166,16): Property 'scaleBand' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (167,16): Property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (169,18): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (169,34): Property 'schemeCategory20' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (189,16): Property 'total' does not exist on type '{}'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (195,16): Property 'axisLeft' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart/prg-stacked-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (208,16): Property 'axisBottom' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-sankey-chart/prg-sankey-chart.component.ts (97,24): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-dual-axis-chart/prg-dual-axis-chart.component.ts (129,20): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-dual-axis-chart/prg-dual-axis-chart.component.ts (179,12): Property 'scaleBand' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-dual-axis-chart/prg-dual-axis-chart.component.ts (180,12): Property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-dual-axis-chart/prg-dual-axis-chart.component.ts (181,13): Property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-dual-axis-chart/prg-dual-axis-chart.component.ts (190,16): Property 'axisLeft' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-vertical-bar-chart/prg-vertical-bar-chart.component.ts (181,16): Property 'scaleBand' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-dual-axis-chart/prg-dual-axis-chart.component.ts (216,16): Property 'axisBottom' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-dual-axis-chart/prg-dual-axis-chart.component.ts (247,22): Property 'line' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-line-chart/prg-line-chart.component.ts (121,20): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-line-chart/prg-line-chart.component.ts (171,16): Property 'scaleBand' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-line-chart/prg-line-chart.component.ts (172,16): Property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-line-chart/prg-line-chart.component.ts (181,16): Property 'axisLeft' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-line-chart/prg-line-chart.component.ts (194,16): Property 'axisBottom' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-line-chart/prg-line-chart.component.ts (204,26): Property 'line' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-line-chart/prg-line-chart.component.ts (242,38): Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-line-chart/prg-line-chart.component.ts (243,37): Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-area-chart/prg-area-chart.component.ts (126,20): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-area-chart/prg-area-chart.component.ts (176,12): Property 'scaleBand' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-area-chart/prg-area-chart.component.ts (177,12): Property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-area-chart/prg-area-chart.component.ts (190,16): Property 'axisLeft' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-area-chart/prg-area-chart.component.ts (203,16): Property 'axisBottom' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-area-chart/prg-area-chart.component.ts (214,20): Property 'line' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-area-chart/prg-area-chart.component.ts (223,16): Property 'area' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-scatter-chart/prg-scatter-chart.component.ts (131,20): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-scatter-chart/prg-scatter-chart.component.ts (187,16): Property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-scatter-chart/prg-scatter-chart.component.ts (188,16): Property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-scatter-chart/prg-scatter-chart.component.ts (199,16): Property 'axisLeft' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-scatter-chart/prg-scatter-chart.component.ts (213,16): Property 'axisBottom' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-scatter-chart/prg-scatter-chart.component.ts (257,36): Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-scatter-chart/prg-scatter-chart.component.ts (258,35): Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-bubble-chart/prg-bubble-chart.component.ts (131,20): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-bubble-chart/prg-bubble-chart.component.ts (188,25): Property 'pack' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-bubble-chart/prg-bubble-chart.component.ts (191,25): Property 'hierarchy' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-horizontal-bar-chart/prg-horizontal-bar-chart.component.ts (123,20): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-horizontal-bar-chart/prg-horizontal-bar-chart.component.ts (172,16): Property 'scaleBand' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-horizontal-bar-chart/prg-horizontal-bar-chart.component.ts (173,16): Property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-horizontal-bar-chart/prg-horizontal-bar-chart.component.ts (181,16): Property 'axisLeft' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-charts/prg-d3/prg-horizontal-bar-chart/prg-horizontal-bar-chart.component.ts (194,16): Property 'axisBottom' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-custom-components/prg-axc-hz-bar/prg-axc-hz-bar.component.ts (112,20): Property 'scaleOrdinal' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-custom-components/prg-axc-hz-bar/prg-axc-hz-bar.component.ts (155,16): Property 'scaleBand' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-custom-components/prg-axc-hz-bar/prg-axc-hz-bar.component.ts (156,16): Property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-custom-components/prg-axc-hz-bar/prg-axc-hz-bar.component.ts (171,29): Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-custom-components/prg-axc-hz-bar/prg-axc-hz-bar.component.ts (174,29): Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
      Property 'pageY' does not exist on type 'Event'.
    ERROR in /home/progen/ProGenALLFiles/ProGen/Pi3.0Angular/PI3_20171124/src/app/pi-layout/prg-custom-components/prg-axc-hz-bar/prg-axc-hz-bar.component.ts (179,26): Argument of type '(d: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(datum: any, index: number, outerIndex: number) => Primitive'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Primitive'.
```

### Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
            "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
            "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
            "@types/d3-sankey": "^0.7.2",
            "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.6.0",
            "angular2-grid": "^2.0.7",
            "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^1.3.0",
            "core-js": "^2.4.1",
            "d3": "^4.12.0",
            "d3-sankey": "^0.7.1",
            "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
            "primeng": "^4.2.2",
            "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
            "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@angular/cli": "1.4.5",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
            "@types/c3": "^0.4.47",
            "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
            "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
            "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
            "c3": "^0.4.18",
            "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
            "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
            "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
            "karma": "~1.7.0",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
            "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
            "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
            "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
            "protractor": "~5.1.2",
            "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
            "tslint": "~5.7.0",
            "typescript": "~2.3.3"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

c3 needs d3 3.x, you're referencing d3 4.x

You'll either need to go back to d3 v3 or wait for the work ongoing to update c3 to d3v4, [github issue thread](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/2143) to finish

There may possibly be a way to use both d3 versions in angular, but it's not my specialty, so I duck out of answering that one

PS. I dunno who up-voted it today (13/07), but fyi c3.js now has versions that work with d3 v4 and v5

c3 0.5 --> d3 v4

c3 0.6 --> d3 v5

Answer (score 0):

There are many different type of errors and no code for those, can you please add some code ? You can find the component and line of error from the error logs you posted.

About this `(237,29): Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.`, try to use `MouseEvent` instead of `Event`.

Comment: As you can see I have already installed d3 in package.json , inspite of that I am getting error. The projects were running perfect but as I installed c3 , thes errors flooded. I can't understand what to do. Is there, any other way to use both d3.js  and c3.js  together in angular2?